# Django: Flexible users for a home appliance services web app

Tags: django

I am doing a small app that requires a different user tool. The thing is this:

I have a **repair application**. In the company, people can repair their fridge, washing machine and kitchen items (like blender etc). There are different technicians for each (specialized). All customer comes thru one reception but each unit (dept of fridge repair for e.g.) also have a receptionist.

Then there are finance and administration units. So, I was wondering how i would go create a user who is a technician of fridge? When he logs in, i wanna take him to the technician's area so he can see repair related tasks.

And for the finance department, to log in but then go to finance section of the project.

I have created tables for **services provided** (fridge etc) and the **departments** (finance). How do I attach the users to each?

I have seen a post that describes adding fields to the user profile but i failed to attach it to my needs.

How do you guys go doing something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can [extend the user functionality](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) without replacing the Django dUser model.

When logging in the user, you can then check the role this user has and redirect based on that role